# AngularJS Controller with parse.com logIn

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, parse-platform

When i executed this code inside a controller not found:

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="pfcAPP">

<head>

    <body>
    <title>pfcAPP</title>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page">
            <div ng-class="{ 'alert': flash, 'alert-success': flash.type === 'success', 'alert-danger': flash.type === 'error' }" ng-if="flash" ng-bind="flash.message"></div>
            <div ui-view></div>
</div>

    <!-- include Parse-Server files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
    <!-- include Angular files -->
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
<!-- include APP files -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="files/app/app.js"></script>      


</body>

</html>
```

**app.js**

```
    console.log('AppController');
   angular.module('APP',[])
    .run(run);

function run() {
    // keep user logged in after page refresh
    Parse.initialize("APPid","masterkey");
    Parse.serverURL = 'http://pfc:1337/parse';
    Parse.User.logIn('luisbg', 'test', {
        success: function(user) {
            // Do stuff after successful login.
            console.log(user);
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            // The login failed. Check error to see why.
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

}
```

but if I execute this code out of controller, it found.

```
Parse.User.logIn('luisbg', 'test', {
                success: function (user) {
                  //  console.log(user);
                },
                error: function(user,error) {
                    console.log(error);
                }
            });
```

i got this error:

```
parse-1.6.14.min.js:15 POST http://192.168.2.103:3000/proxy/http%3A%2F%2Fpfc%3A1337%2Fparse%2Flogin 404 (Not Found) 
(index):120 s {code: 107, message: "Received an error with invalid JSON from Parse: Cannot GET /parse/login/parse/login↵"}
```

I have changed the nGroute for ui.router, and i have probed execute this code in other controller, and i have had the same problem in others controllers.

if I put code out of angular module, i will be OK.

```
    console.log('AppController');
Parse.initialize("APPid","masterkey");
        Parse.serverURL = 'http://pfc:1337/parse';
        Parse.User.logIn('luisbg', 'test', {
            success: function(user) {
                // Do stuff after successful login.
                console.log(user);
            },
            error: function(user, error) {
                // The login failed. Check error to see why.
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
       angular.module('APP',[])
        .run(run);

    function run() {
        // keep user logged in after page refresh


    }
```

With this code i can login or signup in parse, but when i use inside angular module, it use other url to GET LOGIN:

**GET /parse/login/parse/login instead of GET /parse/login**

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out? @luisbg

Answer (score 1):

I've executed my app without phonegap only in APACHE SERVER and It was all OK.

I will continue looking for what the problem